# Is there a way to hide a method in java based on constructor?

Tags: java

Suppose I have class `Person`. A person can have an age or a car. I would like to make the method `getCar()` available to the user only if the user used the constructor `Person(int age, boolean hasCar)`. So if he created a Person object with `Person(int age)` then the method `getCar` shouldn't be accessible. Is there a way to do that? i.e. hide the `getCar()` method. I would like to do that without using inheritance.

Comment: Who is *the user* in this case? Or more importantly: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: the programmer is the user ...

Comment: Just throw an exception or return null or something if the user attempts to access that method but the person has no car. And if the programmer is the user, then why should they be unable to call that method? The programmer should *know* if it has a car or not.

Comment: Might be possible with inheritance, or might also be doable using reflection. AFAIK, there is no other way.

Comment: @JackTwain Read the link dhke provided and think about your answer, please. He is asking this question for a good reason.

Answer (score 3):

No, and that's a *good* thing.

The code that might call `Person.car()` does not necessarily know **at compile time** how the Person was constructed **at runtime**. The Person may have been created by code compiled separately from another source file, another package, or another library entirely.

What you *can* do with `Person.getCar()`, when the person does not have a car, is one of the following:

- **return null**
- **return a magic value**
- or **throw an exception** (preferably with a hasCar() method, to allow normal execution to avoid throwing an exception).

Alternatively, if you allow inheritance, you could have both a `Person` class and a `PersonWithCar` class, and use `instanceof` to distinguish between them. However, if you follow this approach with more than a few HAS-A attributes, it quickly explodes into many classes.

Comment: Not gonna lie, if I was a user of this API and `getCar` threw an exception, I don't think I would be a happy programmer, and probably would seek a different API if I could.  But this is still good advice

Comment: Good point. I added a note about allowing normal execution to avoid exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: you can't and you shouldn't even try.

When you call the constructor of a class, you have already chosen which type of object to instantiate. Changing the object/class afterwards is --even if possible at all-- just a dirty hack. And dirty hacks should always be last resort.

The *typical* way of achieving what you probably want is to have two classes `Person` and `AdultPerson`, with the latter being a subclass of the former and only the second one having the `getCar()` method.

Then you use the [factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) to create either `Person` or `AdultPerson` objects depending on the age of the person.

I'm not convinced that this is good design, though, since --well-- persons age and hence you may suddenly be faced with the problem of converting a `Person` to an `AdultPerson`.

What's the rationale of not having `hasCar()`, `getCar()`, `canHaveCar()` in in the `Person` class and simply returning `null` or raising an exception if `getCar()` is called on an underage person?

Answer (score 1):

So first off, this is definitely not the standard way to handle this problem. Usually the advice will be one of two things. Either Person has some ability to hold references to cars, or there is a subclass of Person (say CarOwner) that knows about cars but is still an instance of Person

But that said, can you hide the method based on constructor? It may be possible to grab the instance through reflection, find the method you want, and change the visibility of the method at runtime. Though this is just brainstorming more than an answer, and it's likely in so doing the visibility change (if the JVM even allows it) would apply to all instances of the class.

The other option might be to short circuit the method at runtime based on constructor, such that if the wrong constructor is used you always return null, throw an exception, or something like that.

Comment: No, reflection cannot achieve this and frankly, what would be the point? If it doesn't error during compile-time, there's no difference to throwing an exception (or, well, an error) anyway.

Comment: I never said it was a good idea, only that it would be worth playing with. As the first sentence in my answer says changing visibility or accessibility of a method is "definitely not the standard way to handle this."

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible the way you described it, you could make getCar() do nothing if hasCar is false or you could use inheritance anyway.

Comment: How do you make a method "do nothing"? You still either need to throw or return `null` if the method exists.